# Unable to get custom headers in .net/IIS 7.5

Tags: .net, header, call

I've been trying to pull custom headers which I've added in web.config.
I used these codes but not not working for custom headers.

```
NameValueCollection headers = base.Request.Headers; //this gives me only default headers
headers.Get("FIRST_NAME") //this is not working as well.
```

Comment: Please provide the code/config settings you're using. It's very hard to help without the code..

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp to inspect and see if your headers really are sent to the server?

Comment: This is what I've added in config file. I've tried adding directly to IIS response headers as well but can't pull those.
      <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="FIRST_NAME" value="ZUNE" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>